# .sort() method not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function isSorted(set) {
    if(set == set.sort()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This function is supposed to check if an array is sorted properly, but no matter what, it still returns true.

Comment: `set == set.sort()` => would be always true .....

Comment: `sort` sorts in-place. `set` and `set.sort()` still refer to the same array. `==` compares by reference, not by the values in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MDN:
*The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array.*

After set.sort() is invoked, set itself has been sorted, so set will always equal set.sort().

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: “_After `set.sort()` is invoked, `set` itself has been sorted, so `set` will always equal `set.sort()`._” But they’re not equal because they’re both sorted, they’re equal because they refer to the same array.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, `==` compares by reference and hence still refers to the same array. Thereby the condition is always `true`

Use the below method to ensure if the array is sorted or not. Found the method form [here](https://gist.github.com/yorkie/7959685/)

```
/*
 * check the array is sorted
 * return: if positive (ascending) ->  1
 *         if negative (descending) -> -1
 *         not sorted  ->  0
 */
Array.prototype.isSorted = function() {
  return (function(direction) {
    return this.reduce(function(prev, next, i, arr) {
      if (direction === undefined)
        return (direction = prev <= next ? 1 : -1) || true;
      else
        return (direction + 1 ?
          (arr[i-1] <= next) : 
          (arr[i-1] >  next));
    }) ? Number(direction) : false;
  }).call(this);
}

var arr = [3,2,1,0];
arr.isSorted();
```

Or you can create a similar function like this using the above code

```
/*
 * check the array is sorted
 * return: if positive (ascending) ->  1
 *         if negative (descending) -> -1
 *         not sorted  ->  0
 */
function isSorted(myArray) {
  return (function(direction) {
    return myArray.reduce(function(prev, next, i, arr) {
      if (direction === undefined)
        return (direction = prev <= next ? 1 : -1) || true;
      else
        return (direction + 1 ?
          (arr[i-1] <= next) : 
          (arr[i-1] >  next));
    }) ? Number(direction) : false;
  }).call(myArray);
}

var arr = [3,2,1,0];
isSorted(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use another way to check, if an array is sorted. You could use a [*compareFunction*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Parameters) as described by [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and use it as check for test as sorted with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

For example, if you have numbers and a *compareFunction* like

```
var greaterOrEqual = function (a, b ) { return a - b; }
```

you could use the function to sort an array with number like

```
array.sort(greaterOrEqual);
```

and you could use the following pattern for checking every element

```
var isSorted = function (compareFunction) {
        return function (a, i, aa) {
            return !(compareFunction(aa[i - 1], a) > 0);
        };
    };
```

and then use it with an array, like

```
var isSorted = array.every(isSorted(greaterOrEqual));
```

A working example

```js
var greaterOrEqual = function (a, b ) { return a - b; },
    isSorted = function (compareFunction) {
        return function (a, i, aa) {
            return !(compareFunction(aa[i - 1], a) > 0);
        };
    };

console.log([42].every(isSorted(greaterOrEqual)));            // true
console.log([42, 42].every(isSorted(greaterOrEqual)));        // true
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].every(isSorted(greaterOrEqual))); // true
console.log([1, 2, 5, 4, 3].every(isSorted(greaterOrEqual))); // false
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```